# Define a list and conditionally add element to it on one line

Tags: python

I have some code like this

```py
import subprocess

long = True

subprocess.run(["ls", "--color"])
```

I want to add `-l` to the list of arguments if `long` is true. I can do it in 3 extra lines

```py
ls_command = ["ls", "--color"]
if long:
    ls_command.append("-l")
subprocess.run(ls_command)
```

or without extra lines:

```py
subprocess.run(["ls", "--color"] + (["-l"] if long else []))

subprocess.run(["ls", "--color", *(["-l"] if long else [])])
```

The issue is this is that it's not too readable (and verbose, the `else []` feels useless) and if you forget the brackets on the last argument, you're going to get `[]` instead of `["ls", "--color"]` when `long` is false. Is there a better way?

Comment: What is wrong about your second code example? Seems very readable and verbose enough.

Comment: @Saddy it's 3 lines longer and I have to come up with a variable name. But yea, I guess it is the way to go.

Comment: Actually the first one is much better.... but what's wrong with 3 lines @Boris over obscurity and flexibility/extensibility?

Comment: Your original approach, `if long: ls_command.append("-l")` is better. In fact, I would say it is ideal and pythonic.

Comment: The #1 goal of code should be clarity.  When you come back in a year to look at this code, you'll immediately understand your 3-line solution.  Stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like this:

```
import subprocess

long = True
ls_command = ["ls", "--color"]

subprocess.run(ls_command if not long else ls_command + ['-l'])
```

or, if you don't like `if not`, you can flip it around

```
import subprocess

long = True
ls_command = ["ls", "--color"]

subprocess.run(ls_command + ['-l'] if long else ls_command)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do this by creating a utility function to hide as much of the ugliness as possible.  Here's an example. Maybe there's a way to make it even a little cleaner than this:

```
long = True

def argif(flag, *cmd):
    return list(cmd) if flag else []

subprocess.run(["ls", "--color"] + argif(long, "-l"))
```

Comment: I don't know if this is warranted for this single-flag case, but generalizing it to take a dictionary could be nice if you have multiple booleans to translate into flags.

Comment: Awe c'mon.  What's wrong with this?  It's the most readable option here.

Comment: What does "not warranted" mean?  You want the line itself to be as readable as possible.  Even for one line, you improve readability by removing the part of the code from view that doesn't contribute any real information.  And, of course, if you do this in more than one place, it's a bigger win.  This is just an option that adds to readability.  I don't see how anyone could think this a BAD answer.

Comment: Hey, it's not my downvote. All I meant is that personally, I probably wouldn't write a function if I were only adding one possible flag, one time—but that yes, this makes a lot of sense if you find you need to expand or generalize.